# Как из Delphi приложения передать параметры для SQL-запроса в отчёт FastReport?

Tags: mysql, delphi, fastreport

Долго мучился, но создал отчёт (опыт всего 2 дня с FastReport)
Там, в самом FastReport, в компоненте `TfrxADOQuery`, элемента `ADOQuery1` есть параметр `SQL`, в котором я создал запрос.
Из FastReport срабатывает.
Из Delphi приложения тоже отчёт срабатывает на отлично. Отчёт формируется по заданному мной запросу.
Но вот хочется не статический запрос использовать, а динамический. Т.е.   пользователь из ПО (Delphi приложение) вбил данные, и эти данные пошли в запрос. Сформировался отчёт исходя из новых, введённых пользователем данных.
Вопрос: к
ак из Delphi приложения передать в параметр `SQL`, FastReport'ного `ADOQuery1` какие либо данные? Или хоть даже сам запрос (новый, допустим).
Чувствую, что что-то надо делать с этим компонентом: TfrxADOQuery. 
Но что делать, не могу сообразить.
Помогите сдвинуться с "творческого" затыка.

---

UPD:
Допустим, как реализовать из Delphi такую конструкцию для FastReports:

```
  frxReport1.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\data\Server_Report.fr3');

  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT `зайцы`, `косят`, `траву` FROM `на_поляне` LIMIT 10');
  ADOQuery1.Open;

  // вот тут как-то и нужно передать в frxReport1 этот SQL запрос.
  frxReport1.DataSet:=ADOQuery1;
  // или как-то, что-то типа вот такого
  TfrxADOQuery.SQL.Text:='SELECT `зайцы`, `косят`, `траву` FROM `на_поляне` LIMIT 10';


  frxReport1.ShowReport();

  ADOQuery1.Close;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
```

Можно ли что-то такое реализовать? Знаю - можно. Только вот как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. В Delphi на форму помещаем элемент `frxDBDateset1`.
   В коде передаём результат в DataSource `DataSource1.DataSet:=ADOQuery1;`
   в свойствах `frxDBDataset1.DataSource` укажем `DataSource1`.
2. В FastReport'е организуем передачу данных:
   через "Отчёт" > "Данные" - выберем `frxDBDateset1` с нужной нам формы.
3. Выставляем в элементе `MasterDate` выставим источник данных - `frxDBDateset1`
4. А далее дело техники. Принимаем всё по нужным нам полям: `[frxDBDataset1."зайцы"]`   `[frxDBDataset1."косят"]`   `[frxDBDataset1."траву"]`.

Comment: Обычно так не делается, потому, что внешний вид отчета "заточен" под те данные что он выводит. Не имея текста запроса внутри отчета, можно делать только самые простые вещи, типа таблицы на N столбцов. Тем более, что так вам приходится разносить перечисление полей `зайцы`, `косят`, `траву` на 2 компонента - в код запроса в программе, и в поля отчета. В итоге вы теряете многие бонусы, которые дают FastReport отчеты.

Answer (score 1):

По идее, запрос пишется в самом отчете, в нем же в свойствах привязываются параметры (параметры нужно заранее в отчете объявить).

При построении отчета, передается/присваивается строка подключения к БД (или передается готовое подключение, не помню) и передаются значения параметрам. Дальше отчет строится сам.

Answer (score 0):

Вы внешний запрос используете, значит FastReport тут вообще ни при чём. Сдайте запрос с параметрами и присвойте их перед его открытием.